# Python-mode in Emacs. <TAB> results in never ending processs

Tags: emacs, python-mode

If I press `<TAB>` on code that is indented like the one below, Emacs runs into an infinite never-ending process, never fixing the indentation

[image]

I checked with `C-h k` and `<TAB>` is bound to `(py-indent-line &optional ARG RECURSIVE)`, which I think is correct.

This is with the latest stable version of Emacs 24.3 and the latest version (6.1.1) of Python mode.

Comment: thanks for posting, registered at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1163423

Comment: @AndreasRöhler It looks like the problem does not occur if the beginning of the selection starts from the beginning of the first line (i.e. line 237 in the picture above), as opposed to from the beginning of the text block to indent.

Comment: fixed in trunk at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/revision/1221